# Missing md5.h header as I install cmusfm scrobbler for cmus on OS X

Tags: macos, installation, md5, cmus

I'm trying to install [cmusfm](https://github.com/Arkq/cmusfm) to be able to scrobble tracks in cmus.

I am on OS X 11 and when I run the `../configure --enable-libnotify` command from the installation guide for cmusfm I get the following output:

> ```
> ... a lot of checking here ...
> checking openssl/md5.h usability... no
> checking openssl/md5.h presence... no
> checking for openssl/md5.h... no
> configure: error: md5.h header not found
> ```

What should I download?

I've tried to install md5sha1sum using brew however it didn't help. Perhaps I should have restarted my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this exact same problem out on my own.

The steps are:

1. Locate md5.h on your system
2. Set the CFLAGS environment variable to include that location
3. Run cmusfm's configure and install process

If you use homebrew or macports you can execute the following to find the path to md5.h (respectively):

```
find /usr/local -name md5.h # brew
find /opt/local -name md5.h # macports
```

You may also be able to use Finder or Spotlight to find md5.h.

Then do this to tell the compiler to look there:

```
export CFLAGS='-I/your/path/to/openssl/include'
```

For example, mine was

```
export CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2f/include'
```

Then rerun the configure script and make && make install. Good luck!